Unable to import installed module - ollama from langchain
I'm trying to create a simple LLM app. I'm calling an LLM with ollama using langchain.
Langchain ollama usage
I installed all the required dependencies - npm install @langchain/community.
My folder structure looks like this:
├── node_modules\..
├── public
│   ├── index.html
│   └── app.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── server.js

After instantiating the server, I click a button included in the html file which calls app.js.
[app.js]

import { Ollama } from "@langchain/community/llms/ollama";

const chatButton = document.getElementById('chat-button');

chatButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  try {
    console.log('Initializing Ollama client...');
    // const ollama = new Ollama({ host: 'http://localhost:11434' });
    const ollama = new Ollama({
      baseUrl: "http://localhost:11434", // Default value
      model: "llama2", // Default value
    });
    console.log('Ollama client initialized.');

    console.log('Making API request...');
    const response = await ollama.chat({
      model: 'llama2',
      messages: [{ role: 'user', content: 'Why is the sky blue?' }],
    });
    console.log('API response received.');

    console.log('Displaying response:', response.message.content);
    alert(response.message.content);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    alert('An error occurred while fetching the Ollama response.');
  }
});

However, I get the error:
localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@langchain/community/llms/ollama". 

Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I checked the installations multiple times and reinstalled the packages after removing package-locak and clearing cache. Nothing seems to work. Can someone help me resolve this?

why not use ollama-js

It's the same issue when I do that. import cannot recognize ollama
